# Interrupt on PIC16F84A using ASSEMBLY, turn RA1 high when RB0 is interrupted

Tags: assembly, interrupt

When I press the button(interrupts), RA1 won't turn on.

RA0 will be continuously blinking, it's already set in the main.

[Image to my hardware layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxdOQ.jpg)

this is the code to redirect cpu to isr:

```
ORG 000H        ; reset vector
GOTO MAIN       ; jump to label main during reset or startup
ORG 004H        ; interrupt vector
GOTO INT_RTN        ; jump to label INT_RTN or ISR
```

this is how I initialized my MCU:

```
 BSF STATUS, RP0         ; initialize PIC    
 CLRF TRISA  
 MOVLW 01H                   
 MOVWF TRISB                 
 MOVLW 0CH                       
 MOVWF OPTION_REG        
 BSF OPTION_REG, 6      ; interrupt event during rising edge
 BCF INTCON, INTF       ; clear the RB0/INT interrupt flag
 BSF INTCON, INTE       ; unmask (enable) RB0/INT interrupt source
 BSF INTCON, GIE        ; enable all unmasked interrupt 
 BCF STATUS, RP0        ; set register bank to 0
```

and this is the code to handle interrupts:

```
INT_RTN BCF INTCON, GIE     ; disable all unmasked interrupt to prevent 
                            ;interrupt overriding
        BTFSS INTCON, INTF  ; check the RB0/INT interrupt ?ag is ‘1’ 
                            ;  (interrupt source from RB0/INT)
        GOTO EXIT           ; exit ISR if not RB0/INT interrupt
        BSF PORTA, 1            ;sets RA1 to 1 
EXIT    BSF INTCON,  GIE        ; enable all unmasked interrupt
        RETFIE                  ; return from interrupt routine
```

Comment: try with removing the `BTFSS intocon, intf" / "goto", as far as I can see there's no other source for interrupts  (and don't forget to clear the INTF bit before returning)